# Is there a way transfer pages from "Confluence" to "Azure Devops Wiki"

Tags: azure-devops, confluence

I have looked into the documentation for Azure DevOps Wiki, but I wasnt able to find a way where you can export pages from Confluence and migrate it or import it to Azure DevOps. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way transfer pages from “Confluence” to “Azure Devops Wiki”

I am afraid that there is no such way could import the file exported from Confluence into Azure Devops Wiki.

According to [this doc about exporting the Content in Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf59/export-content-to-word-pdf-html-and-xml-792498686.html) , the content could be exported as PDF, Word, Html, Xml format.

But these formats couldn't directly show content on Azure Devops Wiki Page.

This is [an under review feature request.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365753/allow-to-embed-office-files-like-powerpoint-or-vis.html)

If this feature is launched, it seems that your requirements could be met.

You could vote and add comments in it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Confluence provides a rich RESTful API with which you could recurse your Spaces and Pages, extract all needed details and then format/write them appropriate to Azure DevOps Wiki (.md files). This is non-trivial but I've done something similar using PowerShell and the Confluence RESTful APIs.

Comment: I said "iterate your Spaces and Pages". "Recurse your Spaces and Pages" is more accurate.

Comment: Building off @Kevin Liu-MSFT's answer, another alternative comes to mind. Because Azure DevOps Wiki is really a Git repository under the hood, you don't need an import. You just need mark-down files. Transform your exported Confluence files (PDF, Word, Html, Xml) to mark-down (.md), clone your Azure DevOps Wiki's repository and just add them. Something like Pandoc (https://pandoc.org/) should handle the transformation.

Comment: Hey @scottwelker, is this only way for work around? for now..as the feature is still getting developed yet.

Comment: I can not presently think of an alternative to the methods already mentioned here. Best of luck.

Comment: [Confluence space migration to Azure Wikis
#8274](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8274) may provide some additional help/ideas.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround that I just used for a single Confluence wiki article (containing only text and formatting): You could use a tool that converts pasted text to markdown.

Example: [clipboard2markdown](https://github.com/euangoddard/clipboard2markdown) (uses [to-markdown](https://github.com/mixmark-io/turndown)). Live webapplication: https://euangoddard.github.io/clipboard2markdown/

This way, you can paste the text from the Confluence wiki editor and have the web application convert/generate markdown formatted text that you can paste in your Azure DevOps wiki article.

(Found this using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=paste%20to%20markdown)).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Open Your confluence page in edit mode and copy all of the content using keyboard shortcuts.
2. Now go to your Azure DevOps wiki on the desired page choose **Paste as HTML** option from the toolbar & paste the content.
   [image]
3. That's it most of your content is now pasted there as rich text wit almost same layout as we had on confluence.

> Any image hosted on confluence might not render here you need to separately provide a new source of it in the respective `img` tags.

Comment: This would make the page maintenance a nightmare